# Linux: redirecting stdout and stderr

Tags: bash, redirection, pipe, tee

I want to write stdout to a file but also prints stdout and stderr. I tried using tee:

```
prog | tee stdout.txt
```

but this causes the printed stderr and stdout to be interleaved incorrectly, i.e. if the correct output should be

```
OUT1 ERR1
OUT2 ERR2
OUT3 ERR3
OUT4 ERR4
```

using tee might print them out of order, e.g.:

```
ERR1 ERR2
OUT1
OUT2 
OUT3 ERR3 
OUT4
ERR4
```

Is there any way to print both stdout and stderr to screen and also write the stdout to a file without gobbling up the printed output?

Comment: See [Show only stderr on screen but write both stdout and stderr to file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/show-only-stderr-on-screen-but-write-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-file). There's no way unless you're willing to do some programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would forward stdout to a file, then use tail to see the file content as it is written. That means you need to have two terminals open.

Terminal one:

```
prog > stdout.txt
```

Terminal two:

```
tail -f stdout.txt
```

So, in terminal two you will see stdout content as it is written to stdout.txt, and in terminal one you will see stderr. You can also forward both stdout and stderr to a file, and do the same thing. In that case you need to use `prog >& outerr.txt`. (This will work on tcsh, but you can do it in bash, too.)